# React Navigation: "Property 'navigate' does not exist on type"

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, react-navigation

Having the hardest time understanding how to properly type out navigation routes. This is my current setup:

Routes.tsx
Here I set up an AppParamList with all the different stacks and tab types.

```
export type AppParamList = {
  AuthStack: {
    Landing: undefined;
    GetStarted: undefined;
    VerifyOTP: { email: string };
    PrivacyPolicy: undefined;
    TermsOfService: undefined;
  };

  OnboardingStack: {
    Onboarding: undefined;
  };

  AppStack: {
    EventsTab: undefined;
    FriendsTab: undefined;
    SettingsTab: undefined;
  };

  EventsTabStack: {
    Events: undefined;
  };

  FriendsTabStack: {
    Friends: undefined;
    SearchUsers: undefined;
  };

  SettingsTabStack: {
    Settings: undefined;
    EditName: { id: string; name: string };
    EditUsername: { id: string; username: string };
  };
};
```

AuthStack.tsx
This is where I'm consuming that AppParmList with the key of AuthStack.

```
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<AppParamList['AuthStack']>();

export function AuthStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Landing"
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
        animationDuration: 200,
        animation: 'simple_push',
        fullScreenGestureEnabled: true,
        navigationBarColor: theme.colors.white,
      }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Landing" component={LandingScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="GetStarted" component={GetStartedScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="VerifyOTP"
        component={VerifyOTPScreen}
        options={{ gestureEnabled: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen name="TermsOfService" component={TermsOfServiceScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="PrivacyPolicy" component={PrivacyPolicyScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

LandingScreen.tsx
When I am using this in my component. I can't get the navigate to work properly.

```
const LandingScreen = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation<AppParamList['AuthStack']>();
...

<PrimaryButton
text="Get started"
onPress={() => navigation.navigate('GetStarted')}
/>
```

The above throws this error:

`Property 'navigate' does not exist on type '{ Landing: undefined; GetStarted: undefined; VerifyOTP: { email: string; }; PrivacyPolicy: undefined; TermsOfService: undefined; }'.ts(2339)`

[image]

Comment: Check if you write your navigation stack in to <NavigationContainer />

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define type for `useNavigation` hook because it already has it's type declared

just use like this and you should be fine

```
const navigation = useNavigation();
```

Answer (score 0):

you must send navigate as a prop to the commponents. then you can use navigate on LandingScreen and PrimaryButton.

for example if your LandingScreen  is a commponent:

```
<LandingScreen   navigation={navigation}  />
```

then use the prop for navigate:

```
onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.navigate('GetStarted')}}
```